# Small Lookup Join Pyspark

Tags: join, pyspark

In order to build a logic in one of Pyspark code , I have to join distinct values in a big data frame with a small lookup table . What could be the recommended way to execute the same . Is there any quick way to join this with out involving parallel processing or broadcast

df_distinct = Main Data Frame - 10 Million records -- After Distinct ~ around 100 records
dflookup = Look up table - 250 records

df_join= Output ~ 100 records

Comment: ideally if you want to join a small table with a large one, you can `broadcast` the small one during joins. what's your end objective here - something to do with the large table?

Comment: If you look at these data , both are very small dataset . So broadcast doesn't make any difference . I was looking for some option join both in driver (if possible) without involving other workers itself if that's an option

Comment: you could try to repartition the dataframes to 1 partition only and then perform the join.